# loopback 4 - TypeError: Cannot read property 'all' of undefined

Tags: loopback, loopback4

I'm trying to use the loopback 4, but when I run this query:

```
const AccountA = new AccountRepository(new BANCbDataSource())
const bb = await AccountA.find({where: {title: '34'}});
```

I receive this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'all' of undefined
```

Inside `/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/dao.js:1797:27)`

I really dont know what is happening ...

My datasource:

```
import {inject, lifeCycleObserver, LifeCycleObserver} from '@loopback/core';
import {juggler} from '@loopback/repository';

const config = {
  name: "bancdv",
  user:" ",
  password: "",
  host:"",
  port: 1234,
  database: ""

}


@lifeCycleObserver('datasource')
export class BANCbDataSource extends juggler.DataSource
  implements LifeCycleObserver {
  static dataSourceName = 'bancdv';
  static readonly defaultConfig = config;

  constructor(
    @inject('datasources.config.bancdv', {optional: true})
    dsConfig: object = config,
  ) {
    super(dsConfig);
  }
}
```

Can someone help me? I already spent 3 days trying a lot of things, but nothing worked..

I expect to get data from database